# "We're sorry, your sql database is unavailable" What does this mean exactly in Azure SQL?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have 5 Azure SQL Database instances all located under the same SQL Server instance in Azure. When I view the "Resource Health" section of any of the databases, I am seeing quite a bit of the messages "we're sorry, your sql database is unavailable" which is concerning.

I am trying to understand though,is this just normal Azure SQL downtime/outage or if there is an issue in my database itself. Looking at the past logs, the DTU usage, etc. do not show any unnecessary strain on the system or usage above my allotted threshold. Yet, I am seeing databases marked as down for several minutes at a time daily from the past two weeks of history that Azure provides.

Comment: That's a question for Azure support

Comment: i too see this,i have raised a support ticket now to know more details

Comment: Interesting. Yup, I raised a ticket with Azure support but am very surprised to not find any documentation or other people talking about this generic error message.

Comment: @mattsonnhalter:Yep,that's a good approach and saves time for both parties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excerpt from Conversation with Azure Support

> This is bug with portal, which is causing to  show these  error messages.This has nothing to do with Availability of database..
>
> this will be fixed soon

In Mail  :

> As discussed the error messages that you saw are due to a known Bug in Azure Postal which should be fixed soon.
>
> Thank you for your time on the phone. It was my pleasure to work with you on this issue.
>
> As agreed over call this support incident will now be archived. If you have further problems within the scope of this issue, please do reopen the support case.

Comment: Azure support has gotten back to me with the same response as well. _"The portal is showing incorrect information regarding availability of the Database.  It is a known issue.  Our Product team is work on the fix for it and it will be release soon.  For time being please ignore that status that it is showing on portal."_ Looks like I've got my answer. Thanks @TheGameiswar.

Comment: _this will be fixed soon_ - four years later and I'm getting this exact error

Comment: @LaughingMan sad to know this